# Search mySQL table for string and return the name of the field it is in

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with 3 columns

title | subtitle | body

I need to search all the rows in the table and return which columns contain the search term. How can I do this?

Ultimately the idea is a basic "find & Replace" system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH(title,subtitle,body) AGAINST (?)",
                                                $yourSearchTerm); //> assuming PDO

while($row = fetch_assoc($query)) {
   foreach( $row as $k=>$v ) {
       if (strpos($v,$yourSearchTerm)!==false)
          echo 'The search word was found in the column: '.$k.'<br />';
   }
}
```

If you don't have pdo

```
  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH(title,subtitle,body) AGAINST ('$yourSearchTerm')");
```

then use

```
   mysql_fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: Uhmk, can you explain it? Im lost around the (?) and  $yourSearchTerm); //> assuming PDO bits?

Comment: @ezra: if you don't know PDO you should google it. Anyway I added the example with plain mysql_query

Comment: I cant get that query to return any results? even running it inside phpmyadmin directly, successfully returns 0 results

Comment: do you have full text index? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM tmdata WHERE MATCH(title,subtitle,body,delivery_price) AGAINST ('$fText')";

Comment: are you sure $fTtext is more than 4 chars and it's a single word contained there? Please consider to assign +1 considering i am helping you. thanks

Comment: $fText is more than 4 chars yes.

Comment: it's a single word contained in your column ? and it's not a stop word  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-stopwords.html  ?

Comment: hmm, no.. not a full word, seems it is working, however.. It would be better if there were no restrictions on the ammount of chars in the search. is this possible?

Comment: yeah that dident turn up much, any that dont require access to the shell?

Comment: you can use LIKE clause. but we are going ot. open a new question